# Dynamically updating images in konva.js

Tags: html, canvas, konvajs

I'm using konva.js for building a simple editor. One of the elements on the canvas is a image that's dynamically generated by a back end server:

The item is a `Image` item and I'm using:

```
this.img.src =  /api/generate_img?arg1=foo&arg2=bar
```

to update it with some trigger.

The flow is working fine but the result isn't great. The image is rendered like it's been drawn several times, each lower than the previous one.

Is this kind of dynamic operation supported?

Comment: Can you provide any jsfiddle? Is your generated image ok?

Comment: Updating the layer with `onload` method make the problem go away. Thanks.